# 1C и PHP. Проблема с обменом данными

Tags: 1с, php, soap

Здравствуйте.

Хочу сразу отметить, что с 1С я не работал. Необходимо сделать обмен данными между 1С и сайтом (на сайт заливать товары, цены и т.д., а в 1С с сайта обновлять кол-во на складе при покупке). Для обмена данными используется SOAP. Первым делом, конечно же, хочется получить для начала хоть какие-то данные. Вот пример кода:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8081/trade1/ws/mobile.1cws?wsdl", array(      
    'login' => "username", 
    'password' => "password",
    'exceptions' => 1, 
    'trace' => 1
));

$response = $client->__soapCall('GetData', array(
    array('DeviceCode' => "12345")
));
var_dump($response->return);
```

Обращаемся к серверу и получаем данные. Во всех примерах в Интернете говорится, что будет XML в результате. Но в моем случае отображаются просто напросто иероглифы непонятные. Как будто с кодировкой что-то не то. Пробовал и кодировку указывать в параметрах к SoapClient, но не помогло.

Кто имел с такими вещами дело и, возможно, сталкивался с такой проблемой, из-за чего такое может быть?

Спасибо.

Comment: Попробовал воспользоваться методом "__getLastResponse", возвращает уже нормальные символы, но вот только опять же непонятно, что они могут значить.
Вот часть примера вывода результата метода

AgFTS2/0iI3BTqDV67a9oKcN7P3bchtJt++L+coRyxF+At9kfBFz7j5BnefDmt+e O0AQojibJGiC6sO6y6rKImsJRHEWADXVvvGj7Cs/g8OOsCP2jW+Xn8Sv4CwAlEii CmSiVcUiNRTfp5ZEisoCMX7/keP4v////J/+d+WP/9//8//9f/nH+B8//eOf/8v

Общая длина строки 92210 символа.
Что этот набор символов может значить?  Закодирован как-то ответ, что ли?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, со своей стороны я все делал верно, но на той стороне 1С неверно генерировал ответ. Админ на той стороне сделал изменения, и обмен данными стал нормальным.

Answer (score 1):

*Пробовал и кодировку указывать в параметрах к SoapClient, но не помогло.*

А тут-то не указано. Может вы правильно указали, но где-то символом ошиблись?
Преобразование из УЖЕ иероглифов вряд ли произойдёт (хотя не факт, конечно).
Кодировка может быть нарушена так же в БД и/или в 1C.

Comment: Вот так пробовал указать кодировку
<code>
$client = new SoapClient("http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8081/trade1/ws/mobile.1cws?wsdl", array(   
    'encoding'=>'ISO-8859-1',
    'login' => "username", 
    'password' => "password",
    'exceptions' => 1, 
    'trace' => 1
));
</code>

Пробовал и UTF-8 указывать